# I'm trying to have a video displaying on my webpage, but it won't load? Is there something wrong with my html code?

Tags: html

This is the html file for my webpage. It's not much but I'm just starting off and trying some things. If i run this as a file on my computer the video will load and play with no problem but on my website it will not load. Can someone help me?

````
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <video width="800" height="600" autoplay loop>
    <source src="rickroll.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</p>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: what are you errors? where is `rickroll.mp4` saved? is the html script in the same folder as the the video?

Comment: there are no errors it doesn't load. rickroll.mp4 is in the same folder as the html script

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Did you try disabling any extenions/plugins/add-ons you might have installed?

Comment: it will work on chrome on my friends windows computer but it takes a few minutes and i don't have any extensions

Comment: How does the styling class look like?  Have you tried width: 100%;  height: 100%;
    top: 0px;  left: 0px;  position: absolute;  background: transparent;  depending on the container of your video.

Comment: i don't have a styling class for it should i add it and see if it works?

Comment: Try `<video width="800" height="600" autoplay  muted>` instead and tell me if it makes a difference in Chrome?